# change search regex pattern in Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I start regex search by C-M-s.

After typing in some pattern, I would like to edit the pattern shown in the bottom bar. But it seems that I can only append new characters at the current pattern, but I can't figure out how to erase the current pattern, (every time hitting backspace key will erase the text in the buffer window not in the bottom bar).

How shall I edit the search regex pattern?

How shall I start over the search i.e. without previous entered regex pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete the last character from the search pattern use `C-M-w`.
You can also enter the minibuffer with `M-e` and then edit the search string.

Comment: And after editing with `M-e`, just use `C-M-s` again.